# Excel freeze when I drag the line between row

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze

There is no easy way (I'm not a native English speaker) to describe this, so I will attach an image and a description for better unstanding.

[image]

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Which Office version?

Comment: If you go to Windows Event Viewer, is there any error recorde under Windows Logs, Applications?